# How to disable auto shutdown on low battery?

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery

I'm using a custom ROM (danielpinto8zz6's Cyanogenmod 12.1 build for the Xiaomi Redmi Note 2, in case anyone is interested) and there's an issue with what I guess is the coulomb counting profile.

The battery drains incredibly fast under certain circumstances leading to a force shutdown. When I then remove the battery briefly and boot the phone up again it shows a realistic charge value instead (like 30% or even 80% depending on the circumstances). I guess removing the battery resets the coulomb counter and causes Android to rely on voltage only?

**Anyway**, is there any way to disable the auto shutdown without using the Xposed module? I can root the phone and edit the system partition -- I just don't want to keep it rooted afterwards.

Alternatively, can I force Android to always use voltage only instead of coulomb counting?

Comment: Are you sure it's the ROM's bug and not the battery is dying?

Comment: Try to recalibrate battery, you have apps for that on play store. What do you mean you can root the phone if you have CM it's allredy rooted. If nobody else have that problem with that ROM, your battery is probably duying, or maybe even some other hardware problem.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје there's no such thing as "recalibrating the battery". It's just a scam to sell in-app advertising. This is all behavior of the kernel, which isn't something you can't readily fix.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! Yes, this is definitely a software issue and not the battery dying. As I said, removing the battery briefly (which probably resets Android's coulomb counter) results in a realistic value and yields quite a lot of usage time. This is an issue with this inofficial Cyanogen mod build.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје: I unrooted the phone. Yes, this is beacause of Pokemon Go. I know, don't judge me. :D

Comment: Well if it's ROM based bug, we can't help you conntact him about bug.

Comment: Just to give you guys an update, I did replace the battery as it was in fact rather old and this solves most of my problem. The coulomb counting issue persists, though -- when I remove the ostensibly empty battery after forced shutdown and immediately replace it I get quite a bit of usable additional capacity.